# my animation doesn't run in cocos2d

Tags: animation, cocos2d-x

In my game I have a "rocket" type and I want to run a sequence of actions on it. At first it must run an explosion animation and then remove itself from the game. For this I used the following code, but it does not work and results in a runtime error.

Rocket class:

```
void Rocket::movingRocket(float dt)
{
    // some codes ...
    if(rocketIsCollideWithEnemy()) // run only one time
    {
        this->stopAllActions();
        CCAnimation *animation = CCAnimation::create();

        for (int i = 0; i < EXPLOSION_FRAME_NUMBER; i++)
        {
            CCString *str = CCString::createWithFormat("/explosion-%d.png", i);
            animation->addSpriteFrameWithFileName(str->getCString());
        }

        animation->setDelayPerUnit(0.06f);
        CCAnimate *animate = CCAnimate::create(animation);
        CCCallFuncN* remove_rocket = CCCallFuncN::create(this, callfuncN_selector(Rocket::removeRocket));

        this->runAction(CCSequence::create(animate,remove_rocket, NULL));
        this->unschedule(schedule_selector(Rocket::movingRocket));
    }
}
```

And for removing a rocket I use:

```
void Rocket::removeRocket(CCObject *pSender)
{
    ((CCNode*)pSender)->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);
}
```

And when I run the above, an error occurs in the following code, part Cocos2d, at line 4:

```
void CCAnimate::update(float t)
{
    // some codes...
    if( splitTime <= t ) 
    {
        CCAnimationFrame* frame = (CCAnimationFrame*)frames->objectAtIndex(i);
        frameToDisplay = frame->getSpriteFrame();
        ((CCSprite*)m_pTarget)->setDisplayFrame(frameToDisplay);

        CCDictionary* dict = frame->getUserInfo();
        if( dict )
        {
            //TODO: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:CCAnimationFrameDisplayedNotification object:target_ userInfo:dict];
        }
        m_nNextFrame = i+1;
    }
    // some codes...
}
```

What could be causing my problem?

Comment: what error? what is the value of i at that point? how is i initialized, perhaps not at all?

Comment: Function of void CCAnimate::update(float t){...} is not developed by me and it's for cocos2d engine and an error occur at this file and line and said that: Unhandled exception at 0x752DCB49 in myClass.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000 . the value of i is 0